# Missing child nodes in view helper

Tags: typo3, fluid

I created a view helper which used to work on TYPO3 7.6 but stopped working on TYPO3 8.7. It always renders the else part even though the return value of `evaluateCondition` is correct while debugging.

While debugging I see that `AbstractConditionViewHelper` in `AbstractConditionViewHelper` gets called and from there `renderThenChild` or `renderElseChild` get called. But there the child nodes are missing.

My view helper:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extkey\ViewHelpers;

class IfRegExpViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper
{

    /**
     * Initialize arguments
     * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception
     */
    public function initializeArguments() {
        $this->registerArgument('then', 'mixed', 'Value to be returned if the condition if met.', false);
        $this->registerArgument('else', 'mixed', 'Value to be returned if the condition if not met.', false);
        $this->registerArgument('value', 'string', 'The value', TRUE);
        $this->registerArgument('pattern', 'string', 'The regex pattern to check', TRUE);
    }

    /**
     * Check if pattern matches
     *
     * @param array $arguments ViewHelper arguments to evaluate the condition for this ViewHelper, allows for flexiblity in overriding this method.
     * @return string the rendered string
     * @api
     */
    protected static function evaluateCondition($arguments = NULL)
    {
        if (preg_match($arguments['pattern'], $arguments['value']) === 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in template:

```
<f:if condition="{eddaylight:IfRegExp(value: overview, pattern: '/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/')}">
    <f:then>
        {overview}
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        something else
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Is there something I need to do that the child nodes get parsed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<f:if condition="{eddaylight:IfRegExp(value: overview, pattern: '/[a-    zA-Z0-9]+/')}">
    <f:then>
        {overview}
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        something else
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Is wrong - the ViewHelper you have written is a condition ViewHelper itself, so it returns either the value of the `then` or `else` node/closure/argument and if none are specified, nothing is returned. What you've written above is the same as:

```
<f:if condition="">
```

Which is obviously false.

The way to use your ViewHelper is:

```
<eddaylight:ifRegExp value="{overview}" pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/">
    <f:then>
        {overview}
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        something else
    </f:else>
</eddaylight:ifRegExp>
```

Same applies to every other subclass of the `AbstractConditionViewHelper`.

Note about childnodes:

- In your current use case there rightfully are no child nodes since you write the ViewHelper in inline notation without passing a child value.
- If you expand to the correct syntax you will see child nodes, *but only until the template gets compiled, at which time child nodes will no longer be set*.

Comment: I did not use me head while creating the template - and I did not even notice the template nesting error while writing the question.
Thank you for your help.